# Issue in proto3 file format data type error

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, protocol-buffers, proto3

I am working on project where I am using nodejs and Proto3 for jobs. I have following proto3 file. where I want to add version as a field.

```
message Request {
    string id = 1;
    string body = 4;
    string createdAt = 5;
    string updatedAt = 6;
    string traceId = 7;
}
```

I have an additional field version, when I was sending this field to it my system was giving error

```
Expect string provided number
```

So I modified it like this

```
message Request {
    string id = 1;
    string body = 4;
    string createdAt = 5;
    string updatedAt = 6;
    string traceId = 7;
    optional int32 version = 8;
}
```

Now I am getting reverse error that it expected integer and getting string. Althought I define here `int32` which is integer in proto3.
I think it is about matching `number` in nodejs and `int32` in proto3. I tried `optional float version = 8;` but still getting.

Here is complete error.

```
message="[rabbit] Request received" 
version_$numberLong="1" 
request.version: number expected" stack="Error: request.version: number expected\n
```

It is saying it expect number and client is sending number `version_$numberLong="1"`. The project is a lot complicated with large files I just condense to show working code. Any solution how can I make them to work together.

Comment: Can client send `version_$numberLong=1` without double quotes?

Comment: I don't have access to the client, actually it is mobile app and then we have `Realmapp` so it is coming from there supposed to be number as it is shown there but not sure where it is converted. I tried other types `fixed32, fixed64, sfixed, and last `google.protobuf.Any` but nothing work.